# Extruding/Sweeping Along Multiple curves

Tags: extrude

Is it possible to extrude a shape, line or plane along multiple curves or paths? What I want to create are sort of accurate roads for a custom map in a racing game. I can figure out how to array curve a shape along a path. But I can't figure out how I can do this with multiple curves.

Because what I want to create is as follows: An uneven road that changes in elevation and angle. Because most roads where I live, are designed to let rainwater slide to the edges of the road, for flat parts of the highway that for example transitions in a curve to the right with the road angle for like 10 degrees.

Is this even remotely possible in Blender, in a sort of ' hassle' free method instead of manually adjusting every vertice?

Comment: Yes, you can do that using geometry nodes